# Why does my C function doesny print anything?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

Here is my main function:

```
void arrCalc(int*, int, int*, int*, int*, double*, int*);
int main()
{
    int a[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, n = 5, *max, *min, *sum, *isEven;
    double *avg;
    arrCalc(a, n, max, min, sum, avg, isEven);
    printf("%d %d %d %lf %d", *max, *min, *sum, *avg, *isEven);
    return 0;
}
```

And here is my fution:

```
void arrCalc(int *arr, int n, int *max, int *min, int *sum, double *avg, int *isEven)
    int i;
    *min = arr[0];
    *max = arr[0];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] < *min)
            *min = arr[i];
        if (arr[i] > *max)
            *max = arr[i];
        if (!(arr[i] % 2))
            *isEven = 1;
        *sum += arr[i];
    }
    *avg = (double) *sum / n;
}
```

When i run the program it prints me nothing. I think it's somehow connected to the definition if min and max in arrCalc. Can someone correct my code please?

Comment: Of cause... you redefine `min` (and also `max`)

Comment: Probably not your main problem, but it wouldn't hurt to print a newline t the end of the line: `printf("%d %d %d %lf %d\n"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `main()`, you declare `min`, `max`, `sum`, and `isEven` as `int*`, but you don't allocate any space for the actual `int`'s that they're supposed to be pointing to. You should just declare these variables as `int` in main, and then pass pointers to them to your `arrCalc` function, like this:

```
int main()
{
    int a[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, n = 5, max, min, sum, isEven;
    double avg;
    arrCalc(a, n, &max, &min, &sum, &avg, &isEven);
    printf("%d %d %d %lf %d", max, min, sum, avg, isEven);
    return 0;
}
```